# nodejs: Identify file clone

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

how to identify if two files are same in javascript(`nodejs`), one is just a renamed copy of other?

**Use case**: I am trying to write a script for syncing a HDD (hdd1) and its clone (hdd2). 95% only video files (size: ~1 GB, count: ~4000). Sometimes I rename the files in `hdd1` and move them different folders. So while syncing, instead of delete and fresh copy from `hdd1` to `hdd2`, I just want to rename and move the files( identified ones) in `hdd2` to match its location in `hdd1`.

Comment: Can't rsync or a similar utility do what you want?

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/aaronm67/node-phash for image files?
You could also try this https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#reading-video-metadata to extract video metadata and attempt to compare that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned by mscdex, there's probably already a tool out there that does what you're looking for (like rsync).

If you're more interested in doing it from scratch as a learning experience, then what you're looking for is called a [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) or hash of a file. Generating a checksum for each file gives you a sort of finger print for a file. You can then use this to compare against the checksum or other files, and if they're the same, the checksums will match as well.

Node.js's [Crypto library](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) gives you methods for generating checksums. [This](http://blog.tompawlak.org/calculate-checksum-hash-nodejs-javascript) blog entry walks through some of this.

Comment: +1 but nodes' built-in crypto libs are made for primarily dealing with strings, using libs like phash and fluent-ffmpeg give easy interfaces to extract media file metadata and marshal it into node data-types.

Comment: While I agree that it makes more sense to use an existing media-specific library to achieve OPs goal, I don't think you're correct in saying that the Crypto library is made for dealing with strings. Node's Crypto methods use streams which means they're made primarily for dealing with streams.

Comment: That's very true, my bad.